# Get time of yesterdays first and last hour

Tags: java, groovy

I need to get yesterdays first time and last time. e.g for today 18 November I need the output

```
2013-11-17 00:00:00
```

and

```
2013-11-17 23:59:59
```

How to get this??

I can get this manually (like getting yesterday date( 17) and put the rest of the value myself) but i need this programmatically  the full form

Comment: The idea is that you make an attempt.

Comment: Can you define what is `full form`?

Comment: i can do this my i am wondering if there is any built in method or not

Comment: the way i showed the output is full form i meant

Comment: How 'bout looking into `org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils`. It might help.

Comment: @LynAs what do you mean with "built in"? Via Calendar.set(...) you can set every field you like to any value you like. As in your case: You want to set hour, minute and second. So yes, there is something "built in".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Groovy, you can get:

```
new Date().previous().clearTime().toCalendar().with { cal ->
    println format( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" )
    add( Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1 )
    add( Calendar.SECOND, -1 )
    println format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
}
```

Or:

```
def dates = new Date().clearTime().with { d ->
    use( groovy.time.TimeCategory ) {
        [ d - 1.day, d - 1.second ]
    }
}
dates.each { println it.format( 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' ) }
```

Comment: this is even better thanks

Answer (score 10):

In Java 8 you can do it via [`java.time` API](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html):

```
LocalDateTime yesterday = LocalDateTime.now().minus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
LocalDateTime time1 = yesterday.with(LocalTime.of(0, 0, 0));
LocalDateTime time2 = yesterday.with(LocalTime.of(23, 59, 59));
```

(Its not hard in Java 7 too, but far less smart)

Answer (score 3):

```
  DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
  cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
  cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
  cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
  cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
  System.out.println(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
  cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
  cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
  cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
  cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 999);
  System.out.println(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Elliott gave us a good Java solution.

Groovyer way will be like this:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

def sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
def cal = new Date().previous().toCalendar() // Obtain previous date
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0) // initialise it
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
println sdf.format(cal.time)
cal++ // Go one day up
cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, -1) // Step back by second
println sdf.format(cal.time)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this:

```
Date getTodayStart( Date inDate){
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    cal.set(inDate[Calendar.YEAR], inDate[Calendar.MONTH], inDate[Calendar.DATE], 0, 0, 0)
    Date todayStart = cal.getTime()
    return todayStart
}

Date getTodayEnd(Date inDate){
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    cal.set(inDate[Calendar.YEAR], inDate[Calendar.MONTH], inDate[Calendar.DATE], 0, 0, -1)
    Date todayEnd = cal.getTime() + 1
    return todayEnd
}
```

And call these method:

```
Date startDate = getTodayStart(date)
Date endDate =  getTodayEnd(date)
```